# How to lock an Excel cell using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I want to lock an Excel cell (none-editable cell) using `Apache POI`. I'm using `HSSFWorkbook` and here what I've tried so far.

First I created a style.

```
Font mystyle = workbook.createFont();
headerFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 11);
style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setLocked(true);
```

Then I added it like below.

```
resultCell.setCellValue("mystyle");
resultCell.setCellStyle((CellStyle) formatter.styles.get("mystyle"));
```

But it doesn't lock the cell, still I can edit the cell. Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: Please refer this discussion > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250095/how-to-make-cell-as-read-only-in-excel-using-apachi-poi

Comment: @sulabhsingh I checked it also. It doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: You need [protecting the Sheet](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#protectSheet-java.lang.String-) to cell locking taking effect.

Comment: @AxelRichter I tried it too. I protected the sheet. But in this case whole sheet is protected and I can't edit any cell even I set it as `setLocked(false)`

Comment: For me it works. And it is how Excel does it. All cells are locked by default according to their cell styles. You need setting the locking to false if you wants editing the cell while the sheet is protected.