# How to create unprotected cells by default on a protected sheet?

Tags: java, apache-poi

When I'm creating protected sheets using Apache POI, all cells are protected by default. I have to unlock each cell individually. Is it possible to protect a sheet while all cells are unprotected by default (so that I protect only the cells I want).

(code used)

```
/*for sheet protection*/
sheet.protected("password");
/*creating style to unlock cell */
CellStyle unlockedCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
unlockedCellStyle.setLocked(false);

/*applying unlock style to cell */  
cell.setCellStyle(unlockedCellStyle);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502552/make-column-as-read-only-using-apache-poi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to have created cells default to unlocked; locked is the default.  But you are on the right track by creating a `CellStyle` with locked set to false.  Make sure that you set locked to false on any and all of your new `CellStyle` objects that you want to be unlocked.  Additionally, Excel has a limit on the number of cell styles that can be created in a `Workbook`, so re-use your `CellStyle` object(s) with each `Cell` you create.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change default cell style in apache POI.
Instead of creating a new cell style for your cell if you had done `getCellStyle()` on your cell, this would have returned the default cell style, and you would be able to edit it,
according to [this](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCellStyle()).

`getCellStyle` never returns null, in case of new cells it returns the default cell style.

So basically to edit default cell style of a cell, either do `getCellStyle` on a newly created cell or try this `workbook.getCellStyleAt(0)`.
Refer to [this](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#getCellStyleAt(int)) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

you can do `XSSFCellStyle defaultCellStyle = wb.getCellStyleAt(0);` to get default cell style and then `defaultCellStyle.setLocked(false);` this will change the default cellStyle of your workbook to unlocked.