# How to unlock a particular cell in excel sheet using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a Excel sheet with some cell as protected . I want to edit their value. I am using Apache POI, tried with the following

```
XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(2);
XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(4);
cell.setCellValue(ssrnMD5);
```

But didn't get successful in editing the cell.
Any suggestion how can i edit those cells

Comment: have you tried unlocking the sheet first? XSSFSheet.disableLocking()

Comment: are you unable to edit even after calling disableLocking? any errors?

Comment: Code is running without error, but value of the cell didn't change

Comment: try setting the CellStyle as specified here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084123/apache-poi-creating-unprotected-cells-by-default-on-a-protected-sheet.  if this doesn't work post your full code for help.

Comment: @Vijay Still not working..