# Apache POI : Make non-editable one column cell

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi

I am working with `spring boot` project, in which we have to export data into `excel` using `Apache POI`. We were given the requirement to make one column to "non-editable" in complete excel.

I tried by setting cell style to set locked but it did not work.

```
CellStyle unlockedCellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
unlockedCellStyle.setLocked(true); //true or false based on the cell.
cell.setCellStyle(unlockedCellStyle);
```

Then I tried to convert the text to an image. The image is created, but I only need one single path that will work for the entire OS and will be accessible to insert into excel.

I tried this code to convert text to image :

```
private void convertDateTexttoImage(){
        int width = 300; // Image width
        int height = 100; // Image height
        String text = "Hello, World!"; // Text to be converted to an image
        // Create a BufferedImage object with the specified width and height
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        // Get the Graphics2D object from the image
        Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
        // Set the background color
        g2d.setColor(java.awt.Color.white);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        // Set the font and color for the text
        java.awt.Font font = new java.awt.Font("Arial", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 24);
        g2d.setFont(font);
        g2d.setColor(java.awt.Color.BLACK);
        // Calculate the position to center the text
        FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
        int textWidth = fm.stringWidth(text);
        int textHeight = fm.getHeight();
        int x = (width - textWidth) / 2;
        int y = (height - textHeight) / 2 + fm.getAscent();
        // Draw the text on the image
        g2d.drawString(text, x, y);
        g2d.dispose();
        // Save the image to a file
        try {
            File outputFile = new File("text_image.jpg");
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputFile);            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error saving image: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

How can I get such `accessible path` for creating an image from text, so that I can use it to insert into my excel.

Or is there any other way so that I can make a non-editable cell in my excel file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache POI - Excel Write - Lock Single Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777156/apache-poi-excel-write-lock-single-cell)

Comment: Try adding sheet.protectSheet("");