# How to protect only 1st row in Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to create a template for end user to upload data, but I wan't to protect my 1st row as non-editable. So the user can't edit the column headings.

I searched the **SO** and I found most of solutions where it is saying how to make un-protect specific cell. But it is not filling my requirement.

**I tried below approach but didn't succeeded. It had thrown some error.**

```
/** We now need something to iterate through the cells.**/
                objHSSFSheet.protectSheet("password");
                  CellStyle unlockedCellStyle = objHSSFWorkbook.createCellStyle();
                  unlockedCellStyle.setLocked(false);
                  for(int i=1; i<65535; i++){
                      for(int j=0; j<254; j++){
                          objHSSFSheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).setCellStyle(unlockedCellStyle);
                      }
                  }
```

***I also attached my error console (view by clicking on View Code Snippet)***

```html
java.lang.IllegalStateException
 at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipResponse.getWriter(GZipResponse.java:150)
 at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:105)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.MetaInfoCacheServletResponse.getWriter(MetaInfoCacheServletResponse.java:315)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:221)
 at org.apache.jsp.html.common.error_jsp._jspService(error_jsp.java:396)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
 at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
 at com.liferay.portal.struts.StrutsUtil.forward(StrutsUtil.java:98)
 at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.doForward(PortalRequestProcessor.java:279)
 at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(TilesRequestProcessor.java:239)
 at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.internalModuleRelativeForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:341)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForward(RequestProcessor.java:572)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:221)
 at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:173)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
 at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:546)
 at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:523)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
 at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:293)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
 at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
 at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.sendError(PortalImpl.java:6556)
 at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.sendError(PortalImpl.java:6431)
 at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.sendError(PortalUtil.java:1834)
 at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:391)
 at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.doExecute(LayoutAction.java:178)
 at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:79)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
 at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:173)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
 at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:546)
 at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:523)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
 at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:293)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
 at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
 at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:160)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
 at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:123)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
 at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:293)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
 at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:243)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
 at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
 at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:263)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
 at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:320)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
 at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
 at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Jun 16, 2015 11:11:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Main Servlet threw exception
```

I appreciate all your help, Thank's in advance

Comment: What error? *filler*

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746441/making-excel-sheet-read-only) works!

Comment: I added my error console (view by clicking on View Code Snippet)